# How to set Microsoft Word as the owner of a VB6 form?

Tags: ms-word, vb6

We are creating an Add-In to Microsoft word. In this Add-In there is a modeless form and we set it as the Top Most form too as per the requirement. When we minimize the Microsoft word application, the modeless form is not minimized. If we able to set the MS Word as the owner of this form, this problem will solve. Please tell me a way to do this.

This is the code that I am using currently to load the form.

```
Dim Test As Long 

With frmSelectStyle
 .aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=Me
 .Show vbModeless
End With

Test = SetTopMostWindow(frmSelectStyle.hwnd, True)
```

I know that we can set an Owner to a form as follows.

```
frmSelectStyle.Show vbModeless , frmMain
```

But in my case, I need to set the MS Word as the owner. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe the SetParent Windows api?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent. This would require a handle to the word process, but I don't know how available that might be.

Comment: *Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child window cannot be an owner window. An application creates an owned window by specifying the owner's window handle as the hwndParent parameter of CreateWindowEx when it creates a window with the WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_POPUP style. The hwndParent parameter must identify an overlapped or pop-up window.  ... After creating an owned window, an application cannot transfer ownership of the window to another window.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows

Comment: Thank you very much  for your suggestions and comments. I will apply them and check whether they suits to my application.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to use the `SetWindowLong` Windows API function. You can wrap that function in your own "SetOwner" function to make it a bit easier to use. `SetOwner` accepts two Long Windows handles: the first is for your modeless window and the second is for the Word Application main window (the code below is a variation of code originally published at DevX.com).

I've tested the code below and the modeless window does minimize along with Word if Word is minimized.

```
Option Explicit

Private hwndOriginal As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long)
Const GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8)
Function SetOwner(ByVal HwndtoUse, ByVal HwndofOwner) As Long

    SetOwner = SetWindowLong(HwndtoUse, GWL_HWNDPARENT, HwndofOwner)

End Function
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim hWndWord As Long

   ' start an instance of Microsoft Word
   Dim WordApp As Word.Application
   Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   ' make sure it's visible
   WordApp.Application.Visible = True

   ' use the FindWindow API to find a window class of "OpusApp" with the specified Word-application caption
   hWndWord = FindWindow("OpusApp", WordApp.Caption)

   hwndOriginal = SetOwner(Me.hWnd, hWndWord)

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

   SetOwner Me.hWnd, hwndOriginal

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Jazimov ,  Thank you for posting answer.  When using this answer, at the time of form is loading a new word document is opened and when we minimize that word document the form is minimizing too.  But in my scenario, what I want is not creating a new word document since our application is an Add-In in the MS Word. I just want to minimize the form when  I minimize the word document that is already opened. I have your code and replace 'Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")' line with 'Set WordApp =  GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' this line. But it didn't work.

Comment: The answer gives the key to your question, which has to do with setting the owner of a VB6 form (window). When you write "it didn't work", that isn't really enough detail for me to troubleshoot. Why not look at what's going on in the code and do some more troubleshooting? For example, are you getting an hWndWord value from the FindWindow call? If not, then troubleshoot that. If yes, then what EXACTLY isn't working?

Comment: I have replaced the Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") line with Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") since I don't want to create a new Word document and my application is using inside the MS Word. Then the modeless dilaog is  not minimizing when the Word Document is minimizing.

Comment: Yes, GetObject method returns the valid object. I have debug it.

Comment: The only reason CreateObject was in my example is to ensure the presence of a running instance of Word. You do not need to use GetObject--it's not necessary. What is necessary is to get FindWindow to work. Be sure you're passing the correct caption and that FindWindow returns a valid handle.